# JSON Parse Set String

Tags: json

I'm trying to read JSON data  measure and update a table

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"id": "cgk3",  "measures": [[38, 983]],"sid": 30, "did": "dgk1"}');

var conn = $.db.getConnection();
conn.prepareStatement("SET SCHEMA \"xyz\"").execute();

var st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"123\" values(?,?,?)");

st.setString(1, obj.id);
st.setInt(2, obj.measures[1]);    // Whats wrong in here I need toinsert first measure into the table..I mean how to read if the measures comes in like that
st.setString(3, obj.did);

st.execute();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what exactly you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what's not working?

Comment: It looks like measures is an array of arrays. You could try `obj.measures[0][0]`  for 38 and `obj.measures[0][1]` for 983

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access an index that is not in "measures". 
Measures contains an array of arrays, you need to access elements like so:

```
console.log(obj.measures[0][0]);
console.log(obj.measures[0][1]);
```